# Read line by line from a text file and print how I want in shell scripting

Tags: shell

*I want to read below file line by line from a text file and print how I want in shell scripting*

```
Text file content:   
zero#123456  
one#123  
two#12345678
```

I want to print this as:

```
zero@1-6  
one@1-3  
two@1-8
```

I tried the following:

```
file="readFile.txt"     
while IFS= read -r line    
do echo  "$line"     
done  <printf '%s\n' "$file"
```

Comment: And if you have `three#123789`? Should the result be `three@1-9` or something like `three@1-3,7-9`?

Answer (score 1):

Create a script like below: `my_print.sh`

```
file="readFile.txt" 

while IFS= read -r line
do
one=$(echo $line| awk -F'#' '{print $1}') ## This splits the line based on '#' and picks the 1st value. So, we get zero from 'zero#123456 ' 
len=$(echo $line| awk -F'#' '{print $2}'|wc -c)  ## This takes the 2nd value which is 123456 and counts the number of characters
two=$(echo $line| awk -F'#' '{print $2}'| cut -c 1)  ## This picks the 1st character from '123456' which is 1
three=$(echo $line| awk -F'#' '{print $2}'| cut -c $((len-1)))  ## This picks the last character from '123456' which is 6
echo $one@$two-$three  ## This is basically printing the output in the format you wanted 'zero@1-6'
done <"$file"
```

Run it like:

```
mayankp@mayank:~/$ sh my_print.sh 
mayankp@mayank:~/$ cat output.txt 
zero@1-6
one@1-3
two@1-8
```

Let me know of this helps.

Comment: It is working fine but it is just printing one line and not printing the second line. Output:  $ cat output.txt
zero@1-5

Comment: I am writing the output in a file `output.txt`. If you just want to print it, check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks mayank. I tried it but again I am getting it as just one single line. Even I tried to print it in output.txt

Comment: I pasted the tested solution. It works fine on my machine. Are you running it on the  same file as you pasted in your post? Please check, there has to be something very simple that you might be missing.

Comment: Thanks mayank. Could you please explain the steps. It will be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed -r 's/^(.+)#([0-9])[0-9]*([0-9])\s*$/\1@\2-\3/' readFile.txt
```

- `-r`: using extented regular expressions (just to write some stuff without escaping them by a backslash)
- **`s/expr1/expr2/`**: **s**ubstitute `expr1` by `expr2`
- **`epxr1`** is described by a regular expression, relevant matching patterns are caught by 3 capturing groups (parenthesized ones).
- **`epxr2`** retrieves captured strings (`\1`, `\2`, `\3`) and insert them in a formatted output (the one you wanted).

[Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) seems to be interesting to start with them. Also you can check your own regexp with [Regx101.com](https://regex101.com/).

**Update:** Also you could do that with awk:

```
awk -F'#' '{ \
             gsub(/\s*/,"", $2) ; \
             print $1 "@" substr($2, 1, 1) "-" substr($2, length($2), 1) \
           }' < test.txt
```

I added a `gsub()` call because your file seems to have trailing blank characters.

Answer (score 1):

It's no shell scripting (missed that first, sorry) but using perl with combined lookahead and lookbehind for a number:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<=[0-9]).*(?=[0-9])/-/' file
Text file content:   
zero#1-6  
one#1-3  
two#1-8
```

Explained some:

- `s//-/` replace with a  `-`
- `(?<=[0-9])` positive lookbehind, *if preceeded by a number*
- `(?=[0-9])` positive lookahead, *if followed by a number*